# HTTP POST REQUEST USING PHP

Tags: php, http, post, http-post, httprequest

I have captured a HTTP Post request using tamper data . I need to make a php file which repeates the request for 100 times. The POST data has HOST,USER AGENT,ACCEPT,ACCEPT_LANGUAGE,ACCEPT ENCODING,CONTENT TYPE,X-REQUESTED-With,REFERER,CONTENT LENGTH,COOKIE,DNT,CONNECTION,PRAGMA,CXACHE CONTROl and some POSTDATA . Help me make a php script

Comment: *"Help me make a php script"* - Errrmm.. ok. `<?php function yo() { echo "Yowza!"; } yo(); ?>`

Comment: lets help him span some form 100 times, or perhaps not

Comment: @Dagon *"Let them eat cake."* – *M.A.*

Comment: Why are you doing it? Are you testing load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're going to want to look into the cURL library for PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

It's basically a library to help you connect and communicate over various protocols, including HTTP using the POST method.

There's a very simple example on using the library on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Second, you're going to want to note the difference between POST **data**, and HTTP request headers. The items you've listed above read like HTTP request headers, which are transferred with any HTTP request, regardless of the request type (GET/POST/HEAD/PUT, etc.)

This is important, because you're going to have to appropriately set those parameters with curl_setopt; see CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_HEADER here http:// php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php